# What is the entropy of Cu(NO3)2?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I have searched for the entropy of copper nitrate in various tables across the internet* and all I could find was its Hf. Ullmann also didn't give an any better clue.
If it was not measured and released, how can I then calculate it?
*http://www2.ucdsb.on.ca/tiss/stretton/database/inorganic_thermo.htm

Comment: You can't.$\;\!$

Comment: @IvanNeretin I can't but someone else sure can.

Comment: Sure, and that's already covered in the answer by **porphyrin**. It is just that these calculations require quite a bit of data which are even harder to come by than just entropy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the entropy in two ways, however, both need some experimental data. The first is to find tables of how the heat capacity varies with temperature and then use $$S=\int_o^T\frac{C_p}{T}dT+ \frac{\Delta H_x}{T_x} + etc.$$ where the subscript x allows for any phase changes, such as melting or one solid phase changing to another and etc. if there is more than one.

The second way is to use spectroscopic data, and calculate vibrational and rotational energy levels and use the relevant partition functions to calculate the internal entropy and the Sakur -Tetrode Equation for the translation.

There are examples of both methods in 'Basic Chemical Thermodynamics' by E. B. Smith, publ OUP.